# Motherboard with a lot of PCI slots

Tags: motherboard

I need a motherboard with a lot of PCI slots. It's better when it had more than 5 PCI slots.
Because i will put 3 or 5 LAN Card ons it.
Do you have suggestions? Or there are alternatives about how to put 3 or 5 LAN Cards on one computer without a lot of PCI slots?

Comment: this really looks like a buying recommendation question http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ - which is offtopic here

Answer (score 5):

You could buy a server-grade LAN card with multiple ports. Intel [offers](http://www.intel.com/network/connectivity/products/server_adapters.htm) various dual- and quad-port cards on a range of buses.

A server card will be more expensive than a desktop card but you get additional benefits (load balancing, on-board processors, etc.)

Don't forget to check OS driver support if going down this path.

Answer (score 0):

Industrial rack-mount backplanes with a separate CPU card ([example](http://www.gtweb.net/j4200.html)) can have as many as 12 to 14 slots in a single chassis, but tend to be a bit more expensive.

Comment: How about motherboards. How many maximum PCI slots do they have.

Comment: One of the backplanes at the link I provided offers 12 PCI slots.

Comment: It wasn't about backplanes but motherboards.

Comment: @Jawa: A motherboard is just a backplane with the CPU (and associated circuitry) on-board.

Answer (score 0):

EVGA manufactures a somewhat deluxe [motherboard with 7 PCIe slots](http://www.evga.com/articles/00501/). That much components on the board 'requires' it to be something called XL-ATX and is recommended to be used with a chassis with 10 expansion slots.

Also [Asus](http://www.motherboards.org/reviews/motherboards/1913_2.html) and [Supermicro](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/QPI/5500/X8DTH-6F.cfm) have MBs with 7 PCIe slots.